# Animate the switch between not empty listview and empty listview

Tags: android, listview, animation

I have a listview filled with data

at some point the user can wipeout that data and reveal the emptyview that i set up.

I want the listview to vanish from the screen animated, revealing the empty data.

How do that ?

Comment: are you familiar with empty view concept ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the empty view. Simply add a view with `@android:id/empty` to your layout and when the dataset is empty it will be automatically show. For instance:

```
<TextView 
   android:id="@android:id/empty"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: this is not what i am asking
I HAVE an empty view setup exactly like this (as the body of the question says, i have an empty view set up) the question is: how to make the switch between a full listview and an empty listview animated

Comment: well, you should spend a little of bit effort asking question. Still it should be possible, but it's a bit hacky.

Comment: do you have a suggestion ?

Comment: Since I don't have seen the code all is kind of suppositions. 1. I'll change form `@android:id/empty` to `@+id/empty` putting visibility GONE. When the user press on the clear button, you could start an Animation, an AlphaAnimation for instance, and when the animation ends you switch the visibility of both, ListView and empty view

Comment: setting lv.setVisibility(View.GONE) does nothing ?

Comment: if you already have an empty view setup for your ListView, make your empty view a custom one by overriding its setVisibility method and starting there an AlphaAnimation

Comment: I tried your suggestion pskink, but it does not work. The animations are not played, the view just disappears as usual.